# Collaborative editing : document.getElementById not updting the display

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, node.js, socket.io

Please I have this small demo of a collaborative editor in a pub/sub fashion.
Scenario:
Server :S 
Clients : A, B
A sends text S.
S receives text and brodcast to B.
B sends text to S.
**S receives text and brodcast to A, A receive text, but document.getElementById is not updting the display.**

I suspect the problem is with javascript execution order...
I am bit confused, can someone points me what goes wrong with my client ?

Server:

```
    var app = require('express')();
    var http = require('http').createServer(app)
    var io = require('socket.io').listen(http);

    //Server accepting connect on this port
    http.listen(3000);

    //Establishing connection to client and disconnecting
    io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
        console.log('Connected to a new client');

        socket.on('room', function(room) {
            socket.join(room);
            console.log('join room '+ room);

        });
        socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        socket.disconnect();
        console.log('Disconnected from a client');
        });

        var room= 'room1';
        //Data exchange between client and server
        //Server receives new data from a client and broadcast it to others
        socket.on('client_character',function(msg){

        //receive data 
        console.log('Data from client'+msg.buffer);

         socket.in(room).broadcast.emit('server_character',msg.buffer);
        //socket.broadcast.to(room).emit('server_character', msg.buffer);
        //socket.to(room).emit('server_character',msg.buffer);

        });

    });
```

Client:
Run separately on Apache server

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <title>Client</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
        <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/style.css">
     </head>

    <body>
        <textarea id="notepad"></textarea><br/>

        <script>
        $(function () {
            var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000',
                        {'sync disconnect on unload':false}); 


            var room = "room1";
            socket.on('connect', function() {
            socket.emit('room', room);
            });

            //receive character from server
            socket.on('server_character',function(content){
                console.log('From Server:'+ content);
                document.getElementById('notepad').innerHTML=content; 
            });

            //For each typed character
            $('#notepad').on('keypress',function(){
                var character= $('#notepad').val();

                //send character to servers
                socket.emit('client_character',{buffer:character});
                console.log('To Server:'+ {buffer:character} );

            });


        });  
        </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

style.css:

```
    #notepad{
        height:500px;
        width:500px;
        font-size: 14px;
        color: brown;


    }
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "collaborative",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "none",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.10.2",
    "socket.io": "^1.4.5"
  }
}
```

Reference Demo: 
[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I0iikz1F1Lk][1]

Comment: After multiple debugging I have come to realize the problem is in the client side. document.getElementById('notepad').innerHTML=content; is not updating the display when the broadcasted message is received.

Answer (score 0):

I did some thanges in tour code for fix one bug in input and add more logs and this is working here with FF and Chrome ( i dont have IE here )

Server:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(http);

//Server accepting connect on this port
http.listen(3000);

//Establishing connection to client and disconnecting
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('Connected to a new client');

    socket.on('error', function(err) {
        //here i change options
        console.log('Error!', err);
    });

    socket.on('room', function(room) {
        socket.join(room);
        console.log('join room: '+ room);
    });
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        // socket.disconnect();
        console.log('Disconnected from a client');
    });

    var room= 'room1';
    //Data exchange between client and server
    //Server receives new data from a client and broadcast it to others
    socket.on('client_character',function(msg){
        //receive data
        console.log('Data from client: '+msg.buffer);

        socket.in(room).broadcast.emit('server_character',msg.buffer);
        //socket.broadcast.to(room).emit('server_character', msg.buffer);
        //socket.to(room).emit('server_character',msg.buffer);

    });

});
```

Client:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Client</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/style.css">
 </head>

<body>
    <textarea id="notepad"></textarea><br/>

    <script>
    $(function () {
        var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000',
                    {'sync disconnect on unload':false});


        var room = "room1";
        socket.on('connect', function() {
        socket.emit('room', room);
        });

        //receive character from server
        socket.on('server_character',function(content){
            console.log('From Server:'+ content);
            document.getElementById('notepad').innerHTML=content;
        });

        //For each typed character
        $('#notepad').on('keyup',function(){
            var character= $('#notepad').val();

            //send character to servers
            socket.emit('client_character', {buffer:character});
            console.log('To Server:', { buffer:character } );
        });


    });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Alberto, thanks for the quick reply. I seem to have the same behavior. You mentioned that it is working...I am confused. If two clients A, B are connected can you for example type in A and see change in B, then type in B and see changes in  A ?

Comment: Yes it will see the changes but this is not the good way to implement this feature.
If you whant one colaborative editor check Etherpad or Share.js how implements the Operational transform.

Comment: You are right, I am aware of Share.js, Together.Js, Etherpad that are kind of finished products implementing OT. The reason of using socket.io was to go deeper and have more granular control even thought I may end up re-inventing the wheel....